# How to automatically open a file that has a dynamic filename

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, docker, grep, cp

I'm trying to make an automation process, my workflow generates a file automatically, this file is named based on a timestamp and a public key.

Example of the file name : `UTC--2022-03-07T10-53-08.532008168Z--84e9ed8d078f2bdc71e4ca9a322d2f4222c9b7b7`

What I need to do exactly is `cat UTC--2022-03-07T10-53-08.532008168Z--84e9ed8d078f2bdc71e4ca9a322d2f4222c9b7b7` to see the content of the file and parse a specific property in the JSON structure that the file provides.

Exact use case needed - after cat- : `{"address":"84e9ed8d078f2bdc71e4ca9a322d2f4222c9b7b7","crypto":{"cipher":"aes-128-ctr","ciphertext":"a14e5429363ce09903aeccf1afa9ea49a02a4974e0fa032d14f7077ceae21588","cipherparams":{"iv":"a214bcb73a74554bb9be59df158c4d4e"},"kdf":"scrypt","kdfparams":{"dklen":32,"n":262144,"p":1,"r":8,"salt":"d933d92a667eec528299c354e1efe0da730cea2a53a082dbeafc9ed70ca40a71"},"mac":"803325a434a6541c5d93d15f11762d2907e1da1c6520fc33632934565822733d"},"id":"694ca50f-3ae9-4520-94f9-a80003c3f95f","version":3}`

What I need from the JSON is the `value` affected to the `address` and I need to execute the whole process from a docker command.

Is there any way how to detect the file has been created every time to go and grab the address inside and put it to the clipboard (just a simple copy cmd) ?
P.S : the file name is generated from another automated process, I don't have the exact file name to look for it but it has a specific directory where it will be.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: As a partial answer: You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command line to extract the value of `address` property. Like this: `cat data.json | jq -r '.address'`, where json is in the file `data.json`.

Comment: I don't have the name "data.json" it's generated automatically, anyway I can achieve this ?

Comment: What is the criteria for the generation of the file? Is it generated daily at a specific time? Or following a specific event? Is it the only file at a specific location? You need to detail this if the file is to be identified in the first place. Think about which conditions can be set to identify the file you need. An example of identification criteria could be: The newest file that matches a specific regular expression.

Comment: @ArturMeinild The file is generated after a command given on the terminal, and it has a specific location `/root/node/keystore/`, it's the only file in the directory.

Comment: Read `man inotifywatch` and `man -k inotify`

Answer (score 2):

Since you inform that the file is the only available file in a specific directory, and taking into account Michal's comment, you get the information like this:

```
cat /root/node/keystore/* | jq -r '.address'
```

The command `cat /root/node/keystore/*` cats the only file found in the directory, and then you pipe it to the `jq` command as provided by Michal.

If you need to run the command directly on a file inside a Docker container, run the `cat` inside the container like this:

```
docker exec <containername/ID> cat /root/node/keystore/* 2> /dev/null | jq -r '.address'
```

Comment: to do this, I need to install JQ inside the container, the image used doesn't support JQ command.. typing apt-get install jq returns `apt: not found`

Comment: the container is running sh mode

Comment: The problem here is that you're trying to do many things at once. You could also copy out the file from the container first, and then run the `jq` command. Maybe a small script would be good here.

Comment: That is really a good Idea, I'm using docker, because the JSON file is generated from a docker command, can I export the file from the container to the main directory where my Dockerfile exists ?

Comment: Try the last command in my answer. This should run the `cat` inside the container and suppress errors, and then pipe to stdout.